# Integral of a portion of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm struggling with this question:

It says: let $C$ be the portion of the curve $y=2 \sqrt{x} $ between $(1,2)$ and $ (9,6).$

Find $ \int_C3y  \, ds$

Any clue that would assist me?

Comment: I would try $ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \sqrt{1+(y')^2} dx$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$y'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$
$$\int_C3y  \, ds=3\int_1^9 2\sqrt{x} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\, dx$$
$$etc.$$